# How to dynamically re size Jquery resizable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do we dynamically re size the Jquery re sizable?

```
<div id="siteOptWrap">


</div>


   $('#siteOptsWrap').resizable({
        distance: 10,
        handles: "n",
        ghost: true,
        animate: true,
        maxHeight: '600',
        //animateDuration: "fast",
    });
```

--here is where I am trying to re size

```
 $('#siteOptsWrap').resizable().resize({ 'height': '25px' });
```

I would really like to be able to ease the resize. What I am doing I've got a menu that I want to show on about 30% of the screen and about 5 seconds after the window loads I want to ease the menu down.

--Here is an image that shows the menu at the very bottom of the page, which is a tabs jquery control that is wrapped in a jquery resizeable.

I need to ease that bottom menu down after about 5 seconds so that the user does not have to do that to start working.

[image: Menu to resize with easing at bottom of image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the height of the element you need to use [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/), not [.resize](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) which is used to add `resize` event handler.

```
$('#siteOptsWrap').resizable().css({ 'height': '25px' });
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jH8N2/)

Comment: This will definitely work. Thank you. Do you know how to ease the resize?